# How to delete record in Many to Many table in EF without deleting the entities it self ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two entities Users and Roles

```
public partial class User
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

}

```
public partial class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And i have table(RoleUser) in Database contain only userid and role id.
I want to modify the user ,Delete the rows that exist in RoleUser Table and insert new record.
When i used this following code it delete the rows in RoleUser Table and also the roles itself

```
   public void Update(User usr)
    {
        var existingParent = _context.Users
            .Where(p => p.Id == usr.Id)
            .Include(p => p.Roles)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (existingParent != null)
        {
            // Update parent
            _context.Entry(existingParent).CurrentValues.SetValues(usr);

            // Delete children
            foreach (var existingChild in existingParent.Roles.ToList())
            {
                if (!usr.Roles.Any(c => c.Id == existingChild.Id))
                    _context.Roles.Remove(existingChild);
            }
          }
        }
```

The question is how to delete the records that exist in RoleUser Table and insert new records without deleting the entities itself??

Comment: Check your database model. The join table (RoleUser) should be on cascade delete if one of the foreign keys gets deleted (here User). Then you only need to delete the User in your code and database will take care of the RoleUser

Comment: ASP.NET is *completely* unrelated to Entity Framework. ASP.NET (and MVC) are web frameworks, EF is an ORM. If you look for EF answers using ASP.NET terms you won't find what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code for remove

```
_context.Users.find(userId).Roles.Remove(_context.Roles.find(roleId));
_context.SaveChange();
```

And this is code for add

```
_context.Users.find(userId).Roles.Add(_context.Roles.find(roleId));
_context.SaveChange();
```

It will save userid and roleid to table many-to-many

Hope help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this to remove a record only in Many to Many table. Let me know if it works for you.

```
IObjectContextAdapter contextAdapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)_context;
ObjectStateManager stateManager = contextAdapter.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;

stateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(existingParent, existingChild, "Roles", EntityState.Deleted);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

To add new values:

```
_context.Entry(existingParent).Collection("Roles").CurrentValue = values;
```

Where `values` is your list of data to add (should be `IEnumerable` or `ICollection`, so `List<Role>` is ok).
`values` must contains object linked to database.

```
foreach (Role entry in newValues) {
    values.Add(_context.Set(typeof(Role)).Find(entry.Id));
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much ,It worked well with me,But now i need to add the new rows can u give me hint for that

Comment: But this code insert new record in role table .The case is the roles exist before i want only insert it in table(RoleUser).

Comment: `values` must contains roles that are linked to the context. For example: `_context.Role.Where(x => x.Id > 5);`. I do this before: `values.Add(_context.Set(Role).Find(id));`

Comment: I will add   
_context.SaveChanges(); After Delete old rows and another time after add new rows or it will be once at the end ??

Comment: it doesn't work well with me untill i do the previous comment

Comment: In my code I do `SaveChanges()` at the end, after delete and add.

Comment: when i use
 foreach (Role entry in lstRol)
                {
                    lstRoles.Add((Role)_context.Set(Type.GetType("Role",true,true)).Find(entry.Id));
                    //_context.Roles.Attach(entry);
                }
I got exception ___  Additional information: Could not load type 'Role' from assembly 'Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: I used this code and every thing is well now.
 foreach (Role entry in lstRol)
                {
                    lstRoles.Add((Role)_context.Set(typeof(Role)).Find(entry.Id));
                }
Thank u so much for your help ,I  think this question should be closed